# timer complete start repeatCount flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, timer

Just a quick question about the Timer class of Flex 4.
I have a timer object with a set repeatCount. At the end of the set number of cycles, the TIMER_COMPLETE event is triggered and the timer.running changes to false. Now I can call the timer.start() function again.

My question is that at this stage, does it also set the repeatCount property back to zero. Or does one have to explicitly call the timer.reset() function.

Thanks.

Comment: Why didn't you check by yourself? I mean, it probably takes less time to check if the value is reseted or not than writing your question...

Comment: I tried checking but i was not sure what was causing the behavior, was it the feature of the Timer class or was there something I was doing wrong. Thanks for the answer. Put my mind at ease...

Comment: note also that none of the variables are reseted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't reset the repeatCount property